# Cannot read my written file (C Programming Student Database)

Tags: c

We got an assignment to make a program to read what is written inside our text file (name, student number, course, year, section, etc.. etc..) But I can't seem to make it work, can you tell me what's wrong?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct record
{
       char name[50],number[50],course[50],gender;
       int year, section;
       float midterm,final,average,sum;
};

int main()
{
    int a=1,n;
    int passed=0,failed=0;
    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("BSU.txt","r");
    
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
           printf("ERROR!");
           getch();
    }
    
    struct record student[25];
    
    printf("Please input the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(a=0;a<n;a++)
    {
          fscanf(fp, "%f", student[a].average);// I CANNOT MAKE THE FSCANF WORK!!//
    }
    
    getch();        
}
```

Comment: It's appreciated if you don't just tag every programming language that comes up when you type `c`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `fscanf(fp, "%f", &(student[a].average));`?

Comment: You have to take care of file contents i.e in which format you are stored details, based on that you have to read.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It only displays 0.0000

Comment: What's the content of StudentPUP.txt (the first 5-6 lines would be enolugh).

Comment: @MichaelWalz

Student Name: Mark Benedict D. Lutab
Gender: M
Student Number: 2015-04711-MN-0
Course: BSIT
Year: 1
Section: 2

Comment: You are not using `fscanf()` correctly. It won't magically read all the data your want. Please read [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/).

Comment: @BenedictLutab So in your _real_ code you are passing the address to `fscanf()`?

Comment: @BenedictLutab please no screen dumps of text. Post the actual text.

Comment: The format of the file has not been considered

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
fscanf(fp, "%f", &student[a].average);
```

instead of

```
fscanf(fp, "%f", student[a].average);
```

But this allows you only to read a file containing numbers, for example:

```
1.5
1.9
2.7
```

The file you want to read is more compilcated.

So in your `for` loop you need to read 10 lines, extract the relevant information from each line, store that information in the corresponding field of your record, and store the record somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the input file format. 
When you're calling `fscanf` the 'cursor' is located at the first line of your file. What you need to to is to bring the cursor to the line you want to read.

```
Student Name: Andrea Zoelle Jacinto <-- cursor is located at the beginning of this line 
Gender: M
Student Number: 2015-04711-MN-0
Course: BSIT
Year: 1
Section: 2
Midterm Grade: 2.00
Final Grade: 1.75
Average Grade: 1.8 <-- you need the cursor here
```

To achieve that you can use `fgets` in an while loop to get rid of the lines before the desired line.

```
char line[256];
while( fgets(line, 256, fp) && line[0] != 'A'); // line[0] != 'A' makes the loop stop when it reached the desired line
```

Now your cursor is at the desired line, however you need to get rid of the text in front of the value you want to read.

```
Average Grade: 1.8 <-- get rid of "Average Grade: "
```

The good thing is `line` already contains this line, so you can use `sscanf` to read formatted from this string.

```
sscanf(line, "%*s %*s %f", &student[0].average); // note the ampersand in front of student[0].average to get its address
```

Using `%*s` makes `sscanf` ignore the words "Average" and "Grades:" so `%f` will read the desired value.

Comment: Look for the desired line and store it in a string Search for a colon. Build a substring starting behind the colon and going till the end of your stored string. Information about substrings in C can be found with the help of your friend google

Comment: @BenedictLutab _if I try to get the name "Mark Benedict D. Lutab" it only gets "Mark", how can I fix this_ : This calls for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Because it looks like your homework, I will not give you the solution but I tell you where is bug.

You are using fscanf in the incorrect way. This line:

```
fscanf(fp, "%f", &student[a].average);
```

is telling something like: "take somevalue (float type) and write it to student[a].average".
It can't work in your situation, because your data structure is more compilacted.

What have you to do?
First, try to write all data from the file on output.
After that, you should try to parse the line which are you interest :)

Read about getline, sscanf. It could be very helpful for you :)